# Maximum Likelihood Mean Estimation for a Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The variable X is distributed as N(μ, 100). 200 values xi are randomly drawn from the population, but only recorded if each extracted value is greater than 230. Define the variable Y such that yi = 1 if xi > 230. For the given sample, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i = 120$.

a) Provide a maximum likelihood estimator of the probability p that X is greater than 230.

b) Obtain the maximum likelihood estimate of μ.

For point a, you can easily arrive at the log-likelihood of a Bernoulli distribution with the estimated parameter   $\hat{p}_{\text{ML}}=0.6$

For point b, honestly, I have no idea.